# How to fetch data from a table which don't have a unique id

Tags: mysql

1. We have a table that we used to store the points according to a section for a particular id, but the id values are not unique.

   ```
     +---------------------+------+----------+
     | id                  | sec  |   points |
     +---------------------+------+----------+
     |                     | B    |        2 |
     |                     | S    |      183 |
     |                     | T    |     3225 |
     | ht01aa              | A    |    24227 |
     | ht01aa              | O    |      307 |
     | ht01aa              | U    |      466 |
     | ht01ab              | A    |    18640 |
     | ht01ab              | O    |      392 |
     | ht01ab              | U    |      501 |
     +---------------------+------+----------+
   ```
2. We need to change the table structure as mentioned below

   ```
     +--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+
     |    id  |  Sec A  |   Sec O |  Sec U |  Sec B  |   Sec S |  Sec T |
     +--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+
     |        |         |         |        |       2 |    183  |   3225 |
     | ht01aa |  24653  |    149  |   198  |         |         |        |
     | ht01ab |  19259  |    121  |   153  |         |         |        |
     +--------+---------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+
   ```

   Here I need to combine all the points of a id based on the section. What's the best way to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the section limited to just those 6 sections?

Comment: 8 sections @SteBov

Answer (score 1):

You want a pivot table (which isn't a inbuilt function in MySQL, but there are workarounds)

A rough example (I cant test this here):

```
select ID
   sum(if( sec = 'A', 1, 0)
       * points) as Sec A,
   sum(if( sec = 'O', 1, 0)
       * points) as Sec O,
   sum(if( sec = 'U', 1, 0)
       * points) as Sec U,
   sum(if( sec = 'B', 1, 0)
       * points) as Sec B,
   sum(if( sec = 'S', 1, 0)
       * points) as Sec S,
   sum(if( sec = 'T', 1, 0)
       * points) as Sec T,
   sum(if( sec = 'Y', 1, 0)
       * points) as Sec Y,
   sum(if( sec = 'Z', 1, 0)
       * points) as Sec Z
  from [schema].[table]
 group by id
;
```

NOTE: I've put section Y and Z as your additional sections as they don't appear in your example with what they are

If that doesn't work directly here's some external links with more detailed examples:

- https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/mysql/w/wiki/6349.pivoting
- http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Answer (score 0):

If your table now contain only one distinct `sec` value for each `id` than you can create the unique primary key `(id, sec)` for that table. Current table design is way more efficient than planned.